# What does buying chocolate ice-cream in the end implies?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, matchstick-men

In the end of the movie *Matchstick Men*, when Roy goes to the supermarket that he always goes to and buys things he includes the chocolate ice-cream that Angela used to eat at his house when Frank and Angela were cheating him. Does this imply that Angela and Roy still see each other in the future? I mean, Angela knows where Roy is working and Roy has forgiven her for cheating him.

Comment: No it doesn't. Chocolate is common and I think the scene was meant to show he lives a normal life now. There's an outside chance that he buys it in memory of her but there's no evidence that she spends time at his home. Plus there's no reason to give the wife and boyfriend why they're spending time together. Angela seems grateful that Roy doesn't out her so I doubt she wants to tell the boyfriend her past with Roy.